# Any difference leaving off async keyword?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm learning async/await patterns, and wondering how necessary the async keyword is in these types of instances (pseudo code). It appears that my processes are running asynchronously in both methods, so I'm wondering what (if any) difference the async keyword makes....?

```
Private sub Button_Click
 MyLongRunningFunction()
end sub

Private Function MyLongRunningFunction() 'Version with no async keyword
 Task.Run(Function()
  'My long running processes go here
  End Function)
End Function

Private Async Function MyLongRunningFunction() 'Version with async keyword
 Task.Run(Function()
  'My long running processes go here
  End Function)
End Function
```

Comment: You can't have a Function that returns a value without waiting for it to complete its calculation of the value.  That requires awaiting the Task you start.  And that requires Async.  And that requires awaiting the Function in the Button_Click() method.  And that requires Async.  Maybe you meant Sub, hard to tell from fake code.

Comment: In addition to the excellent answer, I would note that `Async` routines will most commonly either return `Task` (equivalent to a non-`Async` `Sub`) or `Task(Of T)` (equivalent to a non-`Async` `Function` returning `T`).  You can have a non-`Async` routine that returns a `Task`, and it will still be `Await`able by the calling routine.  You can even have a routine that returns a `Task` be completely synchronous, in that case it will likely return `Task.CompletedTask`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, the async keyword is not necessary for a method to run asynchronously, but it does enable the use of await, which allows for better handling of asynchronous operations.

When a method is marked with the async keyword, it allows for the use of the await keyword within the method. This allows for better management of asynchronous operations, such as waiting for the completion of an asynchronous task before continuing execution.

Without the async keyword, you can still run code asynchronously using Task.Run, as shown in your example code. However, you won't be able to use await to handle the completion of the task.

In your specific example, both versions of MyLongRunningFunction will run the long-running process asynchronously using Task.Run. However, if you want to wait for the completion of the task before continuing, you will need to use await in the async version of the method.

In general, it's a good practice to mark methods as async when they contain asynchronous operations. This makes it clear to other developers that the method is intended to be used asynchronously and enables the use of await to handle completion of tasks.

Comment: Thank you, Synistic. That's a detail not mentioned in most of the documentation into which I've looked, and is very useful information to know.